# How do I get my Discord bot to send a welcome message?

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

I've watched numerous videos, and followed examples online, and still can't get my discord bot to simply send a message upon a member joining. Maybe I'm missing out on an important update?

```
//require the necessary discord.js classes
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");
const { token } = require("./config.json");

//create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

//when the client is ready, run this code (only once)
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("Online");
});

//sends user a welcome message upon joining
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get('921490782958014576');    
    channel.send("Welcome to the server!!")
});

client.login(token);
```

I get nothing. Nada. I've tried several different pieces of code. I've TRIPLE checked the permissions. This is very frustrating. I've tried unadding and readding the bot to the server. I checked up on the discord.js documentation and nothing seems to be wrong with my code. To me it seems as if the guildMemberAdd isn't emitting anything. I'm using notepad++ to edit my code. I feel I could be using something better for debugging purposes possibly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue may be due to missing intents. Try adding the `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent to your list of intents like so.

```
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS] });
```

discord.js docs: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Intents?scrollTo=s-FLAGS

Developer docs: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateway-intents

Comment: YES! Thank you. This worked.  I feel so stupid for asking. I reviewed the links you sent as well and bookmarked them.